# How to use staking proxy signing the proxied stash's unbond action?

Tags: polkadot-js, staking

You know the controller account is deprecating, and the proxy account function is introduced. I set up a proxy with my validator, but I can't nominate(or other staking functions) if I only have the proxy account auth. Can I use the CLI to solve it?
For example:
I suppose use the `polkadot-js-api tx.staking.unbond 1` with a proxy seed. I tried, but failed, can anyone help me?

Comment: Related to this issue here: https://github.com/polkadot-js/tools/issues/329